# wordpress exclude category - post date

Tags: php, wordpress

I used this piece of code to exclude the date in the single.php file to stop any post Ive placed in category 1. I need to add category 157 as well, however nothing I've tried seems to work.

This is the code that works to exclude one category:

```
<?php if ( !in_category (1)) { ?>
 <div class="postdate"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></div>
```

Ive tried these as well and neither one of these have worked:

```
<?php if ( !in_category (1,157)) { ?>
 <div class="postdate"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></div>
```

```
<?php if ( !in_category ('1','157')) { ?>
 <div class="postdate"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></div>
```

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define more than one category id, you need to cast it as an array. In your third code snippet, you are actually passing category id 1 as your first parameter and 157 as the second parameter of your function. Your code should be:

```
<?php if (!in_category(array(1,157))) { ?>
```

This way it will catch if your post is (or not) in category 1 or 157.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
in_category (array(1,157))
```

If you use more than one parameter in this function, you should this function with array method.

Comment: While this code might answer the question you should add some explanation on why it does so.